# SQL:Display distinct ids for all the set of values from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-analysis

I have a problem where after executing a query i'm getting a result like this

```
DevID   Difference      
-----------------
99       5        
99       10   
99       5        
99       4 
12       8        
12       9 
12       5        
12       6
```

i dont want the duplicate ids,
I should be able to display only one id. 
This could be easily achieved by using distinct however the problem is i also need to display the Difference column. I'm not bothered which value comes in diff but either one of the values for 99 can come there but basically i just need one value for id.
Expected result is something like this.

```
DevID   Difference      
-----------------
99       5        
12       8
```

If it helps this question is continuation of the following question
[Difference of values that belong to same group but stored in two rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59071061/difference-of-values-that-belong-to-same-group-but-stored-in-two-rows)

Comment: But why do you need the difference if you don't care about the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` along with `MAX` or `MIN` or any other aggregation function to get a result as you expected.

```
SELECT DevID, MAX(Difference) 
FROM Yourtablename
GROUP BY DevID
```

Answer (score 0):

use aggregation function `max()`.

```
select DevID, max(Difference) 
from tableA
group by DevID
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this example you need to change this query in your actual query.

**NOTE: As per your expected output for I'm prepared for example.**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    DevID   INT,
    [Difference]     INT
);

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
(99,5),(99,10 ),(99,5),(99,4),(12,8),(12,9),(12,5),(12,6)

--SELECT * FROM @Table
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT DevID,[Difference],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DevID  ORDER BY DevID) AS RN 
    FROM @Table 
) AS Data
WHERE RN=1
ORDER BY [Difference]
```

> Output

[image]